# How to hide the tabBar when push a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My application is a Tabbed Application, and it have several controllers under the tabBarController. One controller is a navigationController, and its root view is a table view. When I click a row of the table view, another view will be pushed in. 
So the question is that when the view is pushed in, how can I hide the tabBar at the bottom?
Besides, I also want to add another tabBar into the pushed view, so I need to alloc a UITabBar or UITabBarController? Or there is another way? Thank you!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

use this methood in the UIViewController class where you want to hide the tabBarController

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return YES;
}
```

**Update**

As suggested by @Yuchen Zhong in his answer, This option is now available in the storyboard itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I used this method but it still did not work. I also used "myViewController.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushe = YES", and it didn't work too. I'm confused about this. Do I need to change my structure or there are better ways? Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar TabBar application with NavigationController as its 1st controller, but in the navigationController I have then only added a tableView, and push the other view's in didSelectRow methood of the table view. have you taken  tableVeiwController instead a simple tableView..??  would be helpful if you paste some of your code here

Comment: Thank you! I did it eventually. It's my own fault that I put the navigationController into a viewController. When I use the navigationController directly, it succeeded. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

You can do this in storyboard now:

1. Select the **UIViewController** in your storyboard
2. Select the checkbox **Hide Bottom Bar on Push**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Set `UIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` when you want hide tab bar.

```
nextViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed method hides the bottom bar with a choppy animation.

Instead I hide the tabbar in viewDidLoad with

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

and restore its presence in viewWillDisappear

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: not nice, as you assume in this VC that another VC on the stack wants the tabbar - also `viewDidLoad` is the wrong location, as it might be called even when this VC does not yet appear, also `self.tabBarController` might be `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Set `true` `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the controller that you want to hide.

For hide all controllers put into `prepare for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```